# Convert an irregular to regular precipitation time series

Tags: r, xts

I have an `xts` series with a year of precipitation data:

```
str(data_prec)
An ‘xts’ object from 2011-01-01 to 2011-12-31 23:55:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:105125, 1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr [1:2] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
 $ tzone : chr ""
```

Part of data looks like:

```
2011-12-15 05:15:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:20:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:25:00, 0.1
2011-12-15 05:30:00, 1.2
2011-12-15 05:31:00, 0.2
2011-12-15 05:32:00, 0.6
2011-12-15 05:33:00, 0.1
2011-12-15 05:35:00, 0.1
2011-12-15 05:36:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:37:00, 0.6
2011-12-15 05:40:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:45:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:50:00, 0.1
```

I need to have my data at each five minutes, by summing the previous data. I've tried to use `aggregate`, `to.minutes5` and `merge` without success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is the closest way I've reached:

```
align.time(period.sum(data_prec,endpoints(data_prec,"minutes",k=5)),300)
```

That gave me:

```
2011-12-15 05:15:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:20:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:25:00, 0      
2011-12-15 05:30:00, 0.1    
2011-12-15 05:35:00, 2.1    
2011-12-15 05:40:00, 0.7    
2011-12-15 05:45:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:50:00, 0      
2011-12-15 05:55:00, 0.1
2011-12-15 06:00:00, 0
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
2011-12-15 05:15:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:20:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:25:00, 0.1
2011-12-15 05:30:00, 1.2
2011-12-15 05:35:00, 1.0
2011-12-15 05:40:00, 0.6
2011-12-15 05:45:00, 0
2011-12-15 05:50:00, 0.1
2011-12-15 05:55:00, 0
2011-12-15 06:00:00, 0
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't treating the times consistently.  By design, the :00 of a minute is the *start* of that minute - e.g. 12:00:00 belongs to the 12:00:00 - 12:59:59.999999 range, aka 12th hour.

So you will need to move your times back a fraction of time to make it the way that I think you are expecting it to be.  That said, your 'hoped for' result isn't consistent either (see the addition below my solution):

**solution**

```
.index(x) <- .index(x) - 1
align.time(period.sum(x, endpoints(x,"mins",k=5)))
                [,1]
2011-12-15 05:15:00  0.0
2011-12-15 05:20:00  0.0
2011-12-15 05:25:00  0.1
2011-12-15 05:30:00  1.2
2011-12-15 05:35:00  1.0
2011-12-15 05:40:00  0.6
2011-12-15 05:45:00  0.0
2011-12-15 05:50:00  0.1
```

**your issue**

```
sum(data_prec)  # the sample data you gave (well, not really gave in reproducible form)
[1] 3.0

# your addition
0.1 + 1.2 + 1 + 0.7 + .1
[1] 3.1
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks @Jeff_R, that's what I was looking for. Epic fail not sum right. Sorry! (I edited the question).